# How to insert into table in java sql? and how to solve http 500 error

Tags: java, sql

im trying to create a simple code where it get `name` from the user and insert it into the table , it first goes to a servlet to check if user left textbox empty or not then to goes to the jsp if correct and then i created a class named `user` to get input from user and insert it into the table my problem is its doesnt insert it into the table after thee run is finished

here is index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="NewServlet" method="POST">
            Name:<input type="text" name="name">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is servlet:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        if(name.equals(""))
        {
            PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
            pw.print("NO");
            
        }
        else
        {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("db.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```

here is class named user:

```
public class user {
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public int num(){
      int num=0;
      Connection con=null;
        try {
             Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
      con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/m","m","m");
      PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Tables "+"(NAME) values"+"(?)");
      stmt.setString(1, getName());
      num=stmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();;
        }
        finally{
           
          try {
              con.close();
          } catch (SQLException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(user.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
            
        }
     return num;
    }
}
```

here is jsp named dp:

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:useBean id="bean1" class="user.user">
            <jsp:setProperty property="name" name="bean1"/>
        </jsp:useBean>
        <%
            int a=bean1.num();
            if(a==1)
            {
                out.print("yes");
            }
            else
            {
                out.print("no");
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

the type of error it prints out:

[image]

Comment: Looks like: "Can you debug this code for me?" Please, check this: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally not a good practice to have database access code in your JSP layer (in your User class which your JSP is accessing with useBean). If your HTML form is posting to your Servlet, move the logic there instead.

The exception is telling you that conn is null when you called conn.close(). The only place where you have this call is in your finally block, so there was another exception that your catch didn't catch, then the conn.close() call failed.

Change your catch to

```
catch (Exception e)
```

so you can see what Exception is occurring. Note that you can't call close on conn if the attempt to get the connection already failed, so guard against that by checking for null first:

```
try {
    if(conn != null){        
        con.close();
    }
    else{
        // conn was null, failed to get a connection!
    }
```

It might also help to check if you successfully get a connection in your main block rather than assuming you do.

Comment: thank that works , but still it return 0 and it didnt insert user data into the table

Comment: i also try to have database code in the servlet and still didnt insert it in the table

Comment: Does your sql insert statement work if you execute from a cli? What does the function 'tables(name)' do? Normally an 'insert into yourtablename values(?)' should work (assuming your table exists and that types you're inserting match the column types)

Comment: yes i tried to execute it directly from cli and it works, the table called "tables" and it has a column named "name" to which i put the user input into it , but still it doesnt work when i run the program

Comment: If you select from the table is your row there? Depending on the database, an insert executed with executeUpdate() can return 0 if it's successful. If you're doing an update then it will return the number of rows updated. See JavaDoc here https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()

Comment: but that doest exclude that fact that the data never inserted into the table in the first place

Comment: I think that's a new question then, e.g. why does this sql not insert a value. As someone else already commented, this isn't a code debugging service: "Questions that fit into one of the categories listed above may be closed by the community because they aren't generally a good fit here or need additional information: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Crossplayer If this answers your original question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)